# Three-state Boolean

Tags: c, boolean, state

What is a good way to create a three-state Boolean in a C-based language?

Comment: Here there be dragons: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Comment: Take an integer and use -1,0,1?

Comment: Step 1) **don't call it a boolean** ^^ It's a tri-value/state (and more later, perhaps) type now. "troolean" comes to mind, but perhaps that's just me [mis-]remembering some cheesy nerd joke...

Comment: You should have a look at the [tribool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/tribool.html) library from Boost.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Default value for bool in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827393/default-value-for-bool-in-c)*

Answer (score 33, accepted):

While others have offered answers, I'd like to offer a justification for the best one.

Use integer values -1/0/1 (or really, any negative/zero/positive).

With this scheme, there is an extremely efficient check for any subset of possible values:

```
(x<0)  /*   {-1} */
(!x)   /*    {0} */
(x>0)  /*    {1} */
(x<=0) /* {-1,0} */
(x)    /* {-1,1} */
(x>=0) /*  {0,1} */
```

On x86, all of these will compile to a single `test` opcode followed by a conditional jump opcode with the appropriate conditions.

If you want to hide the implementation, you can use predicate macros for testing each of the 6 subsets.

Comment: Also, this implementation allows easy implementation of tribool operations. NOT = -1 * value, AND = MIN(value1, value2), OR = MAX(value1, value2). Charts can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic

Answer (score 17):

Instead of just using an `int` directly?  You could `typedef` an `enum`:

```
typedef enum {
   LOW      = 0,
   HIGH     = 1,
   TRISTATE = 2
} TriState;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this implementation does not support boolean logic or operations. A full tribool implementation, like boost::logic::tribool is better for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve a [trinary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) logical Boolean test in effect (that is, define a three-valued boolean variable) in C# .NET using the nullable *bool* type. Just test for the null value and treat that as your third possible state / condition in program flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `int`: zero, positive, and negative would probably be the best way to represent the boolean.

Comment: What?  Using a pointer as a value type?  And how would you distinguish `FALSE` and `NULL`?  Or do you mean a `bool*` that points at either a `bool` or `NULL`.  That's incredibly grim.

Comment: ... I think it was fairly obvious that I meant either `NULL` or *pointers* to false and true, wasn't it?

Comment: @Oli: "Or do you mean a `bool*` that points at either a `bool` or `NULL`" -- Oh? Really? Funny... so since when can a `bool*` point to `NULL`? That's incredibly grim.

Comment: @R..: How is the answer a joke?

Comment: `true` and `false` are not objects but values, so the only way to store pointers to them would be to keep `static const` objects around for your `bool *` to point to, or worse yet use dynamic allocation. All of these solutions are horribly inefficient and ugly to assign to. I can't imagine this as anything but a joke.

Comment: @R..: First, the dynamic allocation method is exactly what I said regarding the "heap", so I don't see why what you wrote is different. And second, there's a reason why my answer has two parts, and a reason why I marked the second part as "probably the best way to represent the boolean." Seems like you're completely ignoring that part?

Comment: @Lambert: If you removed the first paragraph (which is ludicrous!), then your answer would be reasonable...

Comment: i accepted this answer because not all c-based language compilers have preprocessors (IE: ActionScript) so i can't use typedef enum.  using neg/zero/pos int works well.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978: What have typedef and enum (alone or in combination) to do with the pre-processor? Both are part of the C language itself and the pre-processor neither handles nor touches either one. Could you be mixing up enums and DEFINES here?

Answer (score 1):

See [Default value for bool in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827393/default-value-for-bool-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Use an `int`? or `enum`, which is technically the same as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of defeats the purpose of a Boolean. It's supposed to be a fundamental piece of logic that's either on or off.

You can create a logical bit of three-valued logic by toggling another variable, setting the first variable true the next time the loop runs and then reverting the first variable back to false immediately after in the next loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h> // Required. Native C has "booleans", but they're just ints

int main() {
    bool ternary = false;
    bool toggler = false;

    if (ternary == false) {
          if (toggler == false) {
            toggler = true;
        } else {
            toggler = false;

            ternary = true;
        }
    } else {
          ternary = false;
    }

  printf("%d\n", ternary);
}
```

```
>>>false
>>>false
>>>true
```

https://cg5.tutorialspoint.com/share/452/pp3aLdgP

Comment: The link is broken (404).